# What is the best way to get the 50 microchips?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I'm currently on the `The Beryll` mission of the main plot at the part where you are required to get 50 microchips and bring them back to the research station. What is the best way to get these microchips?

I've been trying for hours to supply the chip plant in `Nathan's Voyage`, but it only seems to produce one or two microchips per hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

50 is a small number, your best bet is to traverse a number of chip plants to get what you need.

There's a [handy tool](http://eng.x3tc.ru/x3_tc_map/ware-list.php?s=microchip) that lets you find places that sells them.  Look for the sectors with 2 chip plants and just camp out there, make sure those factories are fully stocked on the resources.

Rather than camping out in your own ship, you can just buy a freighter and order them to dock at the chip plants.  As long as you have the trading system extension on your ship you can purchase/sell items remotely.

Later on, when you have to gather 50000(!!!) microchips for your hub mission, your best bet then is to produce some massive micro chip complexes (they make a lot of money as well after your mission is done).

Comment: I've explored most of the universe (not counting the unknown, pirate and Terran sectors) and I've only found 24 microchips so far. :-(

Comment: @NightExcessive then I would recommend find the chip plants that already have resources and parking some ships there so you can have them gobble up any chips that becomes available right away.  Or, if you have enough money, set up a self sufficient chip loop

Comment: How do I have them automatically buy the chips whenever they become available?

Comment: @NightExcessive you can try doing remote best buy and specifying micro chips.  I don't know if it will work though if there are no microchips available anyhwere.  You'll also want enough ecells and a jumpdrive on your trader (along with the right trading system software).  Personally I just camp them at the chip plant and check in regularly to see if there's anything.  They don't sell out THAT fast.

Comment: I ended up finding a stockpile of 40 built up at an Argon Trading Station after a while of exploring.

Comment: @nightexcessive nice :)

Comment: 50k microchips are needed in TC, not AP.

Answer (score 1):

It is by FAR easier to buy

- 1 cattle ranch
- 1 bakery
- 1 argon microchip plant
- 2 complex construction kits

  and set up a simple station in powercircle*, there are guides on how to do this online.

once you have bought a small hauler (I used a Dolphin, but any hauler will do) and outfitted it with Commodity Logistics Software MK1 and MK2, set its homebase as the chip plant you just built, (you can do this in the command console under configuration)
go to the trade menu and hit **"start comercial representation** to get it going, just leave all the settings on their defaults, it will work fine.

Alternatly, you can supply it yourself instead of automating the process.

*if you wish to set up a non-argon chip plant you will need the corresponding food factories.

The Microchip plant will pump out 4 microchips every 20 minutes (2 minutes at 1000 speed) and for the later microchip mission, you can add a few more microchip plants without slowing production speed if your hauler can keep the sillicone going or you add a sillicone mine (yet another reason why powercircle is nice).